# cannot access internet from docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, wget

I can send request to catalog.data.gov website via wget in host machine but in container I cannot.Also I can send a request another websites via wget in my docker container.How can i solve this issue?In my host,I can send request to all websites properly

Comment: Can you post your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: The machine is behind proxy.Error is : ERROR: cannot verify demo.ckan.org's certificate. Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to demo.ckan.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.